# Get number of yearly GitHub user contributions

Tags: javascript, github, client-side, github-api

User profiles on GitHub display the number of contributions a user has made in the past year:

[image]

I'd like to display this information on my website, preferably without having to introduce any kind of backend. I've looked for it in several places. Nothing is listed in [/users/(me)/](https://api.github.com/users/controversial). Short of scraping the page source, is there a way to retrieve this information? I don't see anything documented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled for parsing the HTML of my profile page using PHP. I begin by downloading the HTML for my profile page:

```
$githubProfile = file_get_contents('https://github.com/controversial');
```

next I find the position of the phrase `contributions in the last year` on the page. The whitespace is strange between `contributions` and `in the last year` so I'm using a regex to match any amount of space.

```
$contributionsIndex = preg_match(
  '/contributions\s+in the last year/',
  $githubProfile,
  $matches,
  PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);
$index = $matches[0][1];
```

Finally, I iterate backwards from this point until I come across a character that is neither a number or a comma in the number. Once this condition becomes false, I know I've found the beginning of the number:

```
$endIndex = $index;

while (is_numeric($githubProfile[$index-2]) || $githubProfile[$index-2] == ',')
  $index--;

$contributionsCount = substr($githubProfile, $index-1, $endIndex-$index);
```

Finally, I echo the number out (without commas)

```
echo(str_replace(',', '', $contributionsCount));
```

Finally, I use an AJAX call from my JavaScript page to get the value from the PHP script.

```
function get(url, callback) {
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onload = e => (callback || console.log)(e.target.responseText);
  xhr.onerror = () => console.log('error');
  xhr.send();
  /* eslint-enable no-console */
}

// Fill in GitHub contributions count
get('contributions-count.php', (resp) => {
  document.getElementById('gh-contributions-count').innerText = resp;
});
```

I'm sure this will be accomplishable more cleanly in the future with GitHub's GraphQL API, but that's still in preview stages.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [GithubAPI](https://developer.github.com/v3/)? Using it, you could run the request from your js file, without implemeting any backend.

For your purpose, I think you could use the following request `https://api.github.com/users/yourUserName/events`. That gives you as result, a list of events related to youUserName.

e.g

```
    [
      {
        "id": "xxxxxxx",
        "type": "PushEvent",
        "actor": {.......},
        "repo": {......},
        "payload": {.......},
        "public": true,
        "created_at": "2016-11-17T21:33:15Z"
      },
      .....
    ]
```

You should go through the list and filter the type = PushEvent and created_at = lastYear.

I hope this can help you!

---

Update: that service is just giving the results for the last 3 months, so other possibility is to check (users/username/repos) and after that check the commits over them (repos/username/repoName/commits)

Comment: Unfortunately, the first page only goes back about 9 days, and to parse everything from the last page would far exceed GitHub API rate limits.

Comment: You're right, it will give you the commits of the last 90 days, I didn't see the restriction in the documentation. Have you tried to you get your repos (users/username/repos) and after that check the commits over them (repos/username/repoName/commits) ?

Comment: I could try that. Thanks @Alan.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to parse the svg calendar data with a xml parser and then sum all `data-count` entries. To avoid CORS issue, you can use a proxy like [urlreq](https://github.com/izuzak/urlreq) living on http://urlreq.appspot.com/req :

```js
const user = 'controversial';

fetch('https://urlreq.appspot.com/req?method=GET&url=https://github.com/users/' + user + '/contributions')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(text) {
    xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
    var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      count += parseInt(nodes[i].getAttribute('data-count'));
    }
    console.log('contributions count : ' + count);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error)
  });
```

Another example using the command line with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022147/2614364)