# Get all public User contributions aka "calendar data" (github api v3)

Tags: curl, github, github-api

I have found many threads - even a couple projects which embed the contribution calendar using api's other than the github api - yet none of these methods or threads actually answer the question. [One comes close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262288/finding-total-contributions-of-a-user-from-github-api) but it's a no go.

I am simply trying to access the total number of contributions for a user as shown in your calendar on the github profile page as shown below...

[image]

The api docs describe collecting Repo Contrib data so i've tried blindly poking at the api with educated guesses to no avail. Does anyone per-chance know if there in fact is a viable endpoint for this data? Do I really need to calculate this info myself or do some dirty html scraping nonsense? This seems dumb... Anyone?

UPDATE:
Here's a solution using cheerio and regex for anyone looking for a quick web scraping solution

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const url = 'https://github.com/archae0pteryx'

function getCommits(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url).then(res => {
            const load = cheerio.load(res.data)
            const parsed = load('div.js-contribution-graph > h2').text()
            const reg = /\d+/g
            const x = parsed.match(reg)
            resolve(x)
        }).catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}


getCommits(url)
    .then(x => console.log(x))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using GraphQL v4

If using [graphql API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) is an option, you can use the [contributionsConnection](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/contributionscollection/) to get the total number of contributions between a specific period of time :

```graphql
{
  viewer {
    contributionsCollection(from: "2020-01-01T00:00:00", to: "2020-12-01T00:00:00") {
      contributionCalendar {
        totalContributions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output :

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "contributionsCollection": {
        "contributionCalendar": {
          "totalContributions": 118
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Parsing the calendar svg

You can use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to parse the XML file you get from your calendar svg : https://github.com/users/archae0pteryx/contributions.

It's better than scraping GitHub website but still fail to use the official API :

```
curl -s "https://github.com/users/archae0pteryx/contributions" | \
     xmlstarlet sel -t -v "sum(//svg/g/g/rect/@data-count)"
```