# GitHub rate limiting preventing return of user commit history

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

I have written code to return the "streak" (how many days in a row) a user has committed to GitHub. Unfortunately, it is recursively making GitHub API requests, which ends up quickly running into rate limiting issues (even with an API token). Is there a better way for me to retrieve this information?

Essentially, what I'm looking for is the "green square" data that displays on a users account page:

[image]

My sample code that is running into rate limiting:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const moment = require('moment');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

const port = 5000;

app.get('/streak/:user', async function (req, res) {
    const yesterdaysDate = moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    try {
        const streakCountTotal = await checkUserCommitForDate(req.params.user, yesterdaysDate);
        res.send({ streakCountTotal });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

});

async function checkUserCommitForDate(user, date) {
    const authorOptions = {
        url: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:${user}+author-date:${date}`,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview',
            'Authorization': `token ${process.env.GITHUB_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
        }
    };
    const committerOptions = {
        url: `https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=committer:${user}+committer-date:${date}`,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.cloak-preview',
            'Authorization': `token ${process.env.GITHUB_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
        }
    };

    const githubAuthorResponse = await promisify(request)(authorOptions);
    const githubCommitterResponse = await promisify(request)(committerOptions);

    const githubAuthorCount = Number(JSON.parse(githubAuthorResponse.body).total_count);
    const githubCommitterCount = Number(JSON.parse(githubCommitterResponse.body).total_count);

    if (isNaN(githubAuthorCount) || isNaN(githubAuthorCount)) {
        throw new Error('GitHub contribution count was not a number. Body of response was:', githubAuthorResponse.body);
    } else if (githubAuthorCount + githubCommitterCount > 0) {
        const previousDaysDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let streakCounter = await checkUserCommitForDate(user, previousDaysDate);
        streakCounter++;
        console.log('streakCounter', streakCounter);
        return streakCounter;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function promisify(fn) {
    return function (...args) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn(...args, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error', err);

                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    };
};

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on port', port);
});
```

Comment: I like to reorganize code like this into streams where you can defer making a callback on the stream handler until the request is finished. This makes for a very neat queue that throttles to one request at a time, plus gives you a convenient spot to take a short break and retry if necessary.

Comment: That would still make the same number of requests though, wouldn't it?

Comment: You'll have to if you want to fetch N resources and there's no bulk method, but at least if they're sequential rather than all fired off in parallel you can control the flow better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the contribution list from the svg contribution calendar data used in the profile page :

https://github.com/users/bertrandmartel/contributions

Parsing the xml is then very straightforward and user contributions stats can be processed using only one request. The following is a nodeJS example using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse xml :

```js
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.get('/streak/:user', function(req, res) {
    request('https://github.com/users/' + req.params.user + '/contributions', function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        processContrib(res, body);
    });
});

function processContrib(res, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var data = [];
    $('svg').find('rect').each(function(index, element) {
        data.push({
            count: parseInt($(element).attr('data-count')),
            date: new Date($(element).attr('data-date'))
        })
    });

    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);

    data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    }).filter(function(el) {
        return el.date.getTime() <= yesterday.getTime();
    });
    var streakCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].count == 0) {
            break;
        }
        streakCount++
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        streak: streakCount
    });
}

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on port', port);
});
```

Note that you can also process contributions stats as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022147/2614364)

The caveat is that it's not using the official API but the events that are considered a contribution on the calendar API are subject to changes. Using the API, you would need to redefine the same conditions as defined [here](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)